# Symbol to separate URLs

Tags: php, arrays, http, url, web

I need to input list of URLs and afterwards to be able to split/explode it into array.
The input goes through textarea or text file.

I was using "," comma symbol at first, but then found out that it is used in some URLs. Now I am using ";" semicolon symbol. I did not encounter any URLs with ";" semicolon yet, but I have read that sometimes ";" is used in URLs.

What symbol would you use to separate URLs? I need it to be as simple and intuitive as possible, because my users are not very experienced in IT.

MY ANSWER: i chose to use new line ("\n", "ENTER") as a seperator - it is simple and intuitive to use and is not present in URLs

Comment: URLs may not contain whitespaces or tab characters, so you could use them

Comment: try to use a | (pipe) sign.

Comment: How about a newline …? For inputting URLs in a textarea, is there anything simpler than one URL = one line?

Comment: @CBroe Newline seems to be a good solution in my case. But for instance if a user is uploading a text file of URLs seperated by newline can there be any issues? As far as I know newline is different in some OS

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [RFC 1738](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1738.html) specification

Taken from it:

> Thus, only alphanumerics, the special characters "$-_.+!*'(),", and
>   reserved characters used for their reserved purposes may be used
>   unencoded within a URL.

Use any character which isn't specified as a valid unencoded character in a URL.

Comment: The relevant spec is RFC 3986.

Comment: Although the 1738 spec contains enough information to validate my answer.

Comment: Ryan: RFC 1738 is obsolete. Citing it when talking about the present doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

How about the caret (^) symbol. It's not allowed for an unencoded URL.

Comment: Neither is `|`, `¬` or `\``

Comment: I know, my point is that you could suggest any character which isn't valid in a URL, it's all a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 0):

The specification (RFC 3986) has the answer: http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc3986.html#delimiting.

And no, ";" can appear in a URI.

Comment: Link to mentioned RFC hosted by the IETF: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#appendix-C